# ListView - Data template and data source in xaml (instant changes in VS designer)

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, visual-studio-designer

I have something like this:

```
          <ListView >
              <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="SomeExistingSymbol" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Some data</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="SomeExistingSymbol2" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Some data 2</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <!--More list view items (grids)-->
         </ListView>
```

I don't want to copy `Grids` over and over. I know I can use binding and data templates.
But I want to have **all data defined in xaml** - is that possible?

The reason is that I need to see **instant changes of data in VS designer**, without building project.

Comment: The only good way out of this is as you mentioned - binding and data templates. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: The reason is (Q edit) that I need to see instant changes of data in VS designer, without building project.

Comment: There is support for design time bindings you know..